# How to use try, except to write a file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function using try and except. I created a file named "file", which contains all student personal information. I want to print the personal information when I input a student name and write it in a new file called "new_file". If the input student name is not included in "file", I want to print "Name Not Found". Since this is an assignment, and I am required to use try blocks. Is there anyone could help? The following is my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBTEy.png)

```py
find_info = input("Please input the student name that you want to search:")

def write_file():
    try:
        for student in student_list:
            if (find_info == student.name):
                print("Find Personal Information of:", student.name)
                with open("/Users/ada/Desktop/new_file.txt", "w") as new_file:
                    new_file.write("Name: " + student.name + ", Student_id: " + student.student_id \
                                   + ", College: " + student.college + ", Citizenship:" + 
                                   student.citizenship \
                                   + ", Phone_number:" + student.phone_number + ", Address:" 
                                   + student.address)
            print("\n")
            print("Student Personal Information Created")
            print("\n")
            break
    except:
        print("\n")
        print("Student Name Not Found")
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? It seems you were able to write this without help.

Comment: Nothing raises an exception to catch if you don't find a match.

Comment: Your code won't even run if there is a syntax error; you typically cannot catch them (though exceptions exist, such as attempting to use `eval` or `exec` to dynamically parse code).

Comment: By the way, it should be "found", not "founded". Using correct spelling gives a better impression with your instructor.

Comment: what is student_list? what is find_info? Where is your "raise"?

Comment: The output is not what I expected, the except part is not working at all. When I input a name that is not included in "file", it did not print "Name Not Found".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Comment: @mkrieger1 The output is not what I expected. How to use try and except?

Comment: What you may be looking for is a for.. else .. structure.. Python s loops have an associated else part which will be executed when the loop completes without hitting any break statementz.. so may be in your case you can raise the exception of student record not found in the else block of for..

Answer (score 0):

You've written your code to check if the student name is what you are looking for before you do anything with it, which is good practice! If you want it to throw an exception, though, you have to let it break or break it yourself. In this case, your `if (find_info == student.name):` checks to see if it exists, but you never tell it what to do `else:`. I would suggest adding an else statement that will throw an exception [`raise NameError("Breaking my stuff!")`] that can then be caught by your `except`. In the spirit of homework assignments, I'll leave the exact placement up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no exceptions thrown on your code, you could remove try..exept, but since you are required to have try and except, I recommend changing your if statement to `assert (find_info == student.name)`, which will throw an `AssertionError` if the clause does not evaluate to `True`. Another option is adding an else statement subsequent to your if statement and `raise` with an exception. hopefully this can be helpful.

Comment: This would make more sense if implemented with separate functions to perform find and write.

Comment: Answer is incorrect. There is a number of exceptions that can be thrown by `open` method hidden under name `OSError`. For example "file not found" or  "unauthorized". Accessing files on hard drive should ALWAYS be surrounded by try/catch. Since distinction of user found/not found is not an "unexpected problem" it should NOT be handled by a custom exception. (Exceptions are slooow)

Comment: The answer is not incorrect. It is simply a method for resolving his/her problem. The exception is not an ```OSError``` because all the data is in a single file, and even if it wasn't there, a new file would've been created. 2- There is no problem with speed in this script, if so, it would've been a separate question about optimization.